# How to delete a mySql table row using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
var table = "users";
var id = 25;

$("#btndel").click(function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure ?")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxdel.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'table': 'table', 
                'id': 'id'
            },
            success: function() {
                location.href = "index.php";
            }
        })
    }
});
```

ajaxdel.php

```
extract($_POST);
$stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM '.$table. ' WHERE id = :id') ;
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
```

Table row is not deleted.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, table row is not deleted.

Comment: don't use `extract()`. register_globals was removed from PHP for good reason, and recreating it for such simple things is just... bad. and you leaving yourself open for [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) ANYWAYS, because you stuff $table into the query directly.

Comment: Lol that's not very safe... never directly execute user-input as code.

Comment: you should also have the table parameterise as you are doing with id.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter for how to secure table name against injection.

Comment: @Bsienn table names can't be parameterized (but still shouldn't be done as is)

Comment: @chris85 I din't knew that Thanks. The way bonaca is doind is so wrong that I had to at least point out SQl injection issue. and many others already pointed bonaca on right direction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unsafe and no one should ever use it.

Comment: In the question, the PHP code is unsafe. But in my answer PHP is safe. Future readers will consider the answers (I hope, but just too bad if not!) and all the comments above.

Answer (score 2):

As a start, you are passing the strings `'table'` and `'id'` as POST parameters, not the contents of the respective variables:

```
data: {'table': 'table', 'id': 'id'},
```

Instead, you want to pass the variable values:

```
data: {'table': table, 'id': id},
```

You should also think very hard about possible vulnerabilities before you let the code anywhere near your production system.

Comment: I wrote `data: {'table': table, 'id': id},` instead of `data: {'table': 'table', 'id': 'id'},` but the row is stil not deleted.
`

Comment: Hey where is this server? Can I POST delete cmds? :p

Comment: @Drew And my good friend [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327) wants to login...

Answer (score 1):

**TimoSta's answer is good**. But I see in comment that it still don't work.

So here is something you could try on your PHP.
It's a more secure way to pass the table name.

**I assume** that you defined your `$db` with the SQL user/pass/DBname **AND** that the SQL user you use has the `DELETE` priviledge.

```
$tableArr=["users"];    // You may add other table names you want to access.

if(in_array($_POST['table'],$tableArr){

    $stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM '.$_POST['table'].' WHERE id = ?') ;
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$_POST['id']);
    $stmt->execute;
}
```